# show() overwritten multiple ajax calls

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

I have one html element (`elem1`) and 2 JS functions (`func1`, `func2`) that hides and shows `elem1` respectively. These JS functions make individual ajax calls and `func2` is calling `func1` internally.

**Problem**: I need to call `func2`, which internally calls `func1`. Calling `func1` hides `elem1`. After calling `func1`, I want to `show` `elem1`. But this `show` is not working.

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/46o93od2/21/

HTML:

```
<div id="elem">
Save ME
</div>
<br/>

<button onclick="func1()" id="func1">Try Func1</button>
<button onclick="func2()" id="func2">Try Func2</button>
```

JS:

```
function func1() {
    $.ajax({
        url: '/echo/json/', //use the correct processing url here
        type: "POST",
        data: {}, // send in your data
        success: function (data) {
            //var aData = JSON.parse(data); // there is no data to parse
                $('#elem').hide();     
        },
        error: function (xhr, errmsg, err) {
            alert('error');
        }
    });
}


function func2() {
    $.ajax({
        url: '/echo/json/', //use the correct processing url here
        type: "POST",
        data: {}, // send in your data
        success: function (data) {
            //var aData = JSON.parse(data); // there is no data to parse
                func1();
            $('#elem').show();     
        },
        error: function (xhr, errmsg, err) {
            alert('error');
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: What is the question? Your errors are because there isn't a JSON string returned to parse. This works https://jsfiddle.net/46o93od2/21/

Comment: `func1()` is asynchronous because of the AJAX. It doesn't hide the element until the response is received. So `func2` shows the element first.

Comment: In the fiddle, don't call `JSON.parse(data)`. jQuery automatically parses it.

Comment: @Barmar: what is my best bet to fix this?

Comment: @spaceman thanks for updating the fiddle. I have updated my question.

Comment: @TheWanderer What are you trying do do? Why does `func2` show the DIV if you don't want it to appear?

Comment: @Barmar: Its a simplified version of the current logic. In func2 I want the div to appear, but I also want the complete functionality of func1.

Comment: @Barmar: make another copy of func1 with hide thing removed and call that ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make `func1` take a callback function that tells it what to do after it gets the response. `func2` can pass a function that shows the element.

```
function func1(callback) {
  $.ajax({
    url: '/echo/json/', //use the correct processing url here
    type: "POST",
    data: {
      json: ''
    }, // send in your data
    success: function(data) {
      if (callback) {
        callback();
      } else {
        $('#elem').hide();
      }
    },
    error: function(xhr, errmsg, err) {
      alert('error');
    }
  });
}


function func2() {
  $.ajax({
    url: '/echo/json/', //use the correct processing url here
    type: "POST",
    data: {
      json: ''
    }, // send in your data
    success: function(data) {
      func1(function() {
        $('#elem').show();
      });
    },
    error: function(xhr, errmsg, err) {
      alert('error');
    }
  });
}
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/barmar/46o93od2/26/)